# adding js for elements added by ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to Angular.

Am working on it since a week.

Can someone tell me how can this be done ?

```
<div class="well" ng-repeat="para in parameter">
            <label>{{para}}:</label>
            **<input id="ex{{$index}}"** data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step=1 data-slider-value="0" style="display:inline" />
            <script>
                    **$('#ex{{index}}').slider({
                        formatter: function (value) {
                            return 'Current value: ' + value;
                        }
                    });**
                }
            </script>
        </div>
```

Comment: <div class='slider' ng-controller="SliderControl">
        <div class="well"ng-repeat="para in parameter">
            <label>{{para}}:</label>
            <input id="ex{{$index}}" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text"  data-slider-step=1 data-slider-value="0" style="width:1000px;display:inline" />
            <script>
                function func(a) {
                    $('#ex' + a).slider({
                        formatter: function (value) {
                            return 'Current value: ' + value;
                        }
});
}
</script>
        </div>
    </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not to use the Slider JS code directly in your HTML.

Better way would be to create a directive and put that piece of code in the directive link function.

it will make sure that the DOM element is available for you.

```
module.directive("addSlider", function() {
  return {
    restrict:"AE",
    link: function() {
      $("input[id^=ex]").slider({
                    formatter: function (value) {
                        return 'Current value: ' + value;
                    }
                });
    }
  }
});
```

in your HTML add it as attribute

```
<input id="ex{{$index}}" add-slider data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step=1 data-slider-value="0" style="display:inline" />
```

Another suggestion, I would like to give is:

instead of putting the JS code in the iterator, use a generic CSS selector like

```
$("input[id^=ex]").slider({
                        formatter: function (value) {
                            return 'Current value: ' + value;
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: It worked.. Another possible solution (though a similar solution to solution you provided) could me marking all with a class... Then the css class selector can be used then.